# Database Plugin for CKFinder users

Tags: php, library, plugin

I have written a small plugin library for CKFinder that I would like some critiques on.

The library is located [here](https://github.com/ekojs/Database_Plugin4CKFinder).

If you are looking for where to start, check out [plugin.php](https://github.com/ekojs/Database_Plugin4CKFinder/blob/master/assets/ckfinder/plugins/ejsplug/plugin.php) and hook function in [here](https://github.com/ekojs/Database_Plugin4CKFinder/blob/master/assets/ckfinder/core/connector/php/php5/CommandHandler/FileUpload.php#L190) in the `assets/ckfinder/core/connector/php/php5/CommandHandler/` folder.

I would really love to hear your critiques on:

- Code quality
- Code clarity
- How to improve
- Security it self in query mysql like I must use prepare-statement,etc.
- Anything else that needs clarification expansion etc
     I have also heard that my static column(like my `column of table` in my `plugin.php`) should be replaced with something more dynamic, How
  would I go about doing that?

I'm more interested in what I'm doing wrong than right.

Any opinions on the actual usefulness of the library are welcome.

**Plugin.php**

```
function onSave2Dbase($jns=null,$fname=null,$arr=null,$newFileName=null) {
    global $config;
    $ejsplug_config = $config['Plugin_ejsplug'];
    $opt_cfg = $config['Plugin_ejsplug']['opt'];

    $Urlpath = $arr->getUrl();
    $Physicalpath = $arr->getServerPath();

    $link = mysql_connect($ejsplug_config['dbhost'], $ejsplug_config['dbuser'], $ejsplug_config['dbpass'])or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($ejsplug_config['dbase']) or die('Could not select database');

    if(isset($_SESSION['IDRole']) && !is_null($arr)){
        $gid = intval($_SESSION['IDRole']);
        $usr = $this->S_dbase("select username from users where IDRole='".$gid."'");
        $usr = $usr['username'];

        switch($jns){
            case 'FileUpload':
            if($arr->getResourceTypeName() == "Images"){
                if($arr->getClientPath() == "/slideshow/"){
                    $this->IUD_dbase("INSERT INTO ".$opt_cfg["main_table"]." (foto, keterangan, url_path, physical_path, create_time, create_by) VALUES ('".$fname."', '".$fname."', '".$Urlpath.$fname."', '".$Physicalpath.$fname."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', '".$usr."')");
                }
                else{
                    $this->IUD_dbase("INSERT INTO ".$opt_cfg["other_table"]." (nama, keterangan, url_path, physical_path, create_time, create_by) VALUES ('".$fname."', '".$fname."', '".$Urlpath.$fname."', '".$Physicalpath.$fname."', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', '".$usr."')");
                }
            }
            else{
                $this->IUD_dbase("INSERT INTO ".$opt_cfg["other_table"]." (nama, keterangan, url_path, physical_path, create_time, create_by) VALUES ('".$fname."', '".$fname."', '".$Urlpath.$fname."', '".$Physicalpath.$fname."', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', '".$usr."')");
            }
            break;

            case 'QuickUpload':
            break;

            case 'DownloadFile':
            case 'Thumbnail':
            break;

            case 'CopyFiles':
            case 'CreateFolder':
            case 'DeleteFiles':
            if($arr->getResourceTypeName() == "Images"){
                if($arr->getClientPath() == "/slideshow/"){
                    $this->IUD_dbase("DELETE FROM ".$opt_cfg["main_table"]." WHERE physical_path ='".$Physicalpath.$fname."'");
                }
                else{
                    $this->IUD_dbase("DELETE FROM ".$opt_cfg["other_table"]." WHERE physical_path ='".$Physicalpath.$fname."'");
                }
            }
            else{
                $this->IUD_dbase("DELETE FROM ".$opt_cfg["other_table"]." WHERE physical_path ='".$Physicalpath.$fname."'");
            }
            break;

            case 'DeleteFolder':
            case 'GetFiles':
            case 'GetFolders':
            case 'Init':
            case 'LoadCookies':
            case 'MoveFiles':
            case 'RenameFile':              
            if($arr->getResourceTypeName() == "Images"){
                if($arr->getClientPath() == "/slideshow/"){
                    $this->IUD_dbase("UPDATE ".$opt_cfg["main_table"]." SET foto='".$newFileName."',keterangan='".$newFileName."',url_path='".$Urlpath.$newFileName."',physical_path='".$Physicalpath.$newFileName."',create_by='".$usr."' WHERE physical_path ='".$Physicalpath.$fname."'");
                }
                else{
                    $this->IUD_dbase("UPDATE ".$opt_cfg["other_table"]." SET nama='".$newFileName."',keterangan='".$newFileName."',url_path='".$Urlpath.$newFileName."',physical_path='".$Physicalpath.$newFileName."',create_by='".$usr."' WHERE physical_path ='".$Physicalpath.$fname."'");
                }
            }
            else{
                $this->IUD_dbase("UPDATE ".$opt_cfg["other_table"]." SET nama='".$newFileName."',keterangan='".$newFileName."',url_path='".$Urlpath.$newFileName."',physical_path='".$Physicalpath.$newFileName."',create_by='".$usr."' WHERE physical_path ='".$Physicalpath.$fname."'");
            }
            break;

            case 'RenameFolder':
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
    }
    mysql_close($link);
    return true;
}

private function S_dbase($sql){
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    return mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
}

private function IUD_dbase($sql){
    // $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

And this is my [config.php](https://github.com/ekojs/Database_Plugin4CKFinder/blob/master/assets/ckfinder/config.php) in ckfinder folder. This is my new modified and not yet committed to my github.

**Config.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

function CheckAuthentication() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['IDRole'])?true:false);
}

$config['LicenseName'] = '';
$config['LicenseKey'] = '';

if(!isset($_SESSION['IDRole'])){
    $_SESSION['IDRole'] = 000;
}

$baseUrl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/demo_ckfinder/trunk/assets/user_files/administrator/';
if ($_SESSION['IDRole'] == '4') {
    $homeDir = '_asus/';
} else if ($_SESSION['IDRole'] == '3') {
    $homeDir = '_pengguna/';
}  else if ($_SESSION['IDRole'] == '2') {
    $homeDir = '_admin/';
}  else if ($_SESSION['IDRole'] == '1') {
    $homeDir = '';
} else {
    $homeDir = '_publik/';
}

$baseDir = resolveUrl($baseUrl);

$config['Thumbnails'] = Array(
    'url' => $baseUrl. '_thumbs',
    'directory' => $baseDir . '_thumbs',
    'enabled' => true,
    'directAccess' => true,
    'maxWidth' => 100,
    'maxHeight' => 100,
    'bmpSupported' => false,
    'quality' => 80);


$config['Images'] = Array(
    'maxWidth' => 1600,
    'maxHeight' => 1200,
    'quality' => 80);

$config['RoleSessionVar'] = 'CKFinder_UserRole';

if ($_SESSION['IDRole'] == '4') {
    $config['AccessControl'][] = Array(
        'role' => '*',
        'resourceType' => '*',
        'folder' => '/',
        'folderView' => true,
        'folderCreate' => true,
        'folderRename' => true,
        'folderDelete' => true,
        'fileView' => true,
        'fileUpload' => true,
        'fileRename' => true,
        'fileDelete' => true);
} else if ($_SESSION['IDRole'] == '3') {
    $config['AccessControl'][] = Array(        
        'role' => '*',
        'resourceType' => '*',
        'folder' => '/',
        'folderView' => true,
        'folderCreate' => false,
        'folderRename' => false,
        'folderDelete' => false,
        'fileView' => true,
        'fileUpload' => true,
        'fileRename' => false,
        'fileDelete' => false);
} else if ($_SESSION['IDRole'] == '2') {
    $config['AccessControl'][] = Array(
        'role' => '*',
        'resourceType' => '*',
        'folder' => '/',
        'folderView' => true,
        'folderCreate' => true,
        'folderRename' => true,
        'folderDelete' => true,
        'fileView' => true,
        'fileUpload' => true,
        'fileRename' => true,
        'fileDelete' => true);
} else if ($_SESSION['IDRole'] == '1') {
    $config['AccessControl'][] = Array(
        'role' => '*',
        'resourceType' => '*',
        'folder' => '/',
        'folderView' => true,
        'folderCreate' => true,
        'folderRename' => true,
        'folderDelete' => true,
        'fileView' => true,
        'fileUpload' => true,
        'fileRename' => true,
        'fileDelete' => true);
} else {
    $config['AccessControl'][] = Array(
        'role' => '*',
        'resourceType' => 'Images',
        'folder' => '/',
        'folderView' => true,
        'folderCreate' => false,
        'folderRename' => false,
        'folderDelete' => false,
        'fileView' => true,
        'fileUpload' => false,
        'fileRename' => false,
        'fileDelete' => false);
}



$config['DefaultResourceTypes'] = '';

$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
    'name' => 'Files', // Single quotes not allowed
    'url' => $baseUrl . 'files'.($homeDir != ''?'/'.$homeDir:$homeDir),
    'directory' => $baseDir . 'files'.($homeDir != ''?'/'.$homeDir:$homeDir),
    'maxSize' => '10M',
    'allowedExtensions' => '7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip',
    'deniedExtensions' => '');

$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
    'name' => 'Images',
    'url' => $baseUrl . 'images'.($homeDir != ''?'/'.$homeDir:$homeDir),
    'directory' => $baseDir . 'images'.($homeDir != ''?'/'.$homeDir:$homeDir),
    'maxSize' => '10M',
    'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
    'deniedExtensions' => '');

$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
    'name' => 'Flash',
    'url' => $baseUrl . 'flash'.($homeDir != ''?'/'.$homeDir:$homeDir),
    'directory' => $baseDir . 'flash'.($homeDir != ''?'/'.$homeDir:$homeDir),
    'maxSize' => '10M',
    'allowedExtensions' => 'swf,flv',
    'deniedExtensions' => '');

$config['CheckDoubleExtension'] = true;

$config['DisallowUnsafeCharacters'] = false;

$config['FilesystemEncoding'] = 'UTF-8';

$config['SecureImageUploads'] = true;

$config['CheckSizeAfterScaling'] = true;

$config['HtmlExtensions'] = array('html', 'htm', 'xml', 'js');

$config['HideFolders'] = Array(".svn", "CVS");

$config['HideFiles'] = Array(".*");

$config['ChmodFiles'] = 0777;

$config['ChmodFolders'] = 0755;

$config['ForceAscii'] = false;

$config['XSendfile'] = false;


include_once "plugins/imageresize/plugin.php";
include_once "plugins/fileeditor/plugin.php";
include_once "plugins/zip/plugin.php";
include_once "plugins/ejsplug/plugin.php";

$config['Plugin_ejsplug'] = array(
    "dbhost" => "your_host",
    "dbuser" => "your_user",
    "dbpass" => "your_pass",
    "dbase" => "your_database",
    "opt" => array(
        "main_table" => "slideshow",
        "other_table" => "userfiles"
    )
);

$config['plugin_imageresize']['smallThumb'] = '90x90';
$config['plugin_imageresize']['mediumThumb'] = '120x120';
$config['plugin_imageresize']['largeThumb'] = '180x180';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Security it self in query mysql like I must use prepare-statement,etc.

Yes, you really should use prepared statements, your current code looks extremely vulnerable. Right now, `$gid` is the only value that you actually validate in some way before putting into a query, all other variables - if user supplied - will lead to an SQL injection (they could have been cleaned by `CKFinder`, but I really would not rely on that, and input validation is at best a nice addition to proper escaping or prepared statements). SQL injection is possible in `update` and `insert` statements, not only `select` statements..

Also note that `mysql_query` is  - as it's documentation says - deprecated since 2013, you really should not be using it anymore. Use either `mysqli` or `PDO`, and use prepared statements.

**Naming**

You should handle your variable names uniformly. Either use camelCase, or snake_case, but don't mix them, as that will make it harder to remember names. Also, don't start variable or function names with an uppercase character.

And don't abbreviate variable names. What is `$jns`? And does `$fname` stand for `$fileName`? Maybe, but why is it written out in `$newFileName`?  `$usr` should be `$username`, etc.

It's also not really clear that `IUD_dbase` stands for `perform insert, update, or delete query`. I would just get rid of it, it doesn't really add any benefit anyways.

**Early Return**

If you turn this if around: `if(isset($_SESSION['IDRole']) && !is_null($arr)){`, then you would save one level of nesting:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['IDRole']) || is_null($arr)){
    mysql_close($link);
    return true;
}
[long block of code]
```

**Misc**

- `return (isset($_SESSION['IDRole'])?true:false` can be written as `return isset($_SESSION['IDRole'])`, but it could also be removed, as you never use it (which is probably good, as you yourself set `$_SESSION['IDRole']`, so it will always be set).
- you repeat `$Physicalpath.$fname` and `$Urlpath.$fname` multiple times. I would probably just save it in a variable.

Comment: +1 it's useful . As you said : "And don't abbreviate variable names. What is `$jns`? And does `$fname` stand for `$fileName`? Maybe, but why is it written out in `$newFileName`? `$usr` should be `$username`, etc.". I though that I'm not consistent enough using English in my variable, `$jns` should be `$command`. :)

Comment: Hello @tim, I've updated my code as your answer.in my free time now... :)
If you've a time to review it again feel free to make some critiques on.